# Crystal Reports PDF Text Issues After Server Migration From AIX to Linux

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

We've been using a cron job to run a Java 6 jar on an AIX server. It grabs a Crystal Reports 2016 report, populates it based on some parameters we give it, then exports the report as a PDF and attaches it to an email. This email is then automatically sent out every morning. It worked flawlessly with that but we were recently migrated over to a Linux box. I've been manually running the job from the console to work out any kinks and the only remaining issue is that the exported PDFs don't render properly after they've been attached to the email.

It appears as though each paragraph and sentence is compressed down to a single spot and all letters are stacked on top of one another. Numbers appear to be fine. Boxes and lines that are used to organize the text also appear but are scattered around the pages randomly. It's probably worth mentioning that this report has text fields that use formulas to display or suppress based on the parameters provided. The final product in the PDF should be 1-2 pages, but these new PDFs are 5-6 pages, so it seems like the formulas aren't working. We've confirmed that the data is present in the PDF stream, so it's there but we just can't see it.

Things we've tried:

- Checked/updated the font ttfs on the server
- Tried different fonts
- Updated the print drivers on the server
- Checked the database connection in Crystal Reports to make sure that no properties had to be updated
- Reformatted the pages and fields in the report
- Upgraded the jar from Java 6 to Java 8

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We switched from OpenJDK to a regular Sun JDK on the server and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the default printer on that machine is set to use a page size that matches the report design.

Or, in the report, using Crystal Reports Designer, go to File, Page Setup... and turn on the option of 'Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Page Size'.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!